# fail transaction and prevent storing it on the chain

Tags: solidity

both `require` and `assert` generate an exception and mark the transaction as failed.

Is there a way to make the transaction not register on the network and hence not incur any cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to have the transaction incur 0 gas cost, in order to protect the miners from spam transactions. `require` and `assert` both burn all of your remaining gas right now.

Starting in Metropolis (by end of year), the assembly instruction `0xfd` aka `REVERT` will halt execution, reverse all state changes, and return all the *remaining* gas.

So in Solidity, it's preferred to use `require()` for input validation, and to use it early in the function. The contract will gain the new functionality automatically with the Ethereum upgrade.

Metropolis Proposal: [EIP 140 - REVERT opcode](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/140)